# add checked elements into my entity

Tags: symfony

I have an entity Equipe (Team) that have OneToMany relation with Employe (a team member). So in order to create a team, in my interface I have a list of all employees and for each employee I have a checkbox, if you checked it means that that employee will be a member of this team. I have no idea how to get it work. This is my entity Equipe.

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OC\UserBundle\Entity\Employe", mappedBy="equipe", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
*/
protected $employe;
```

this my entity Employe

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OC\EquipeBundle\Entity\Equipe", inversedBy="employe")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Eq_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE") 
     */
    protected $equipe;
```

and this is my twig to add a team

```
 {%for c in agents %}
    {%if (( c.direction == app.user) )%}
         <tr class="odd gradeX">
             <td>{{c.id}}</td>                                                              
             <td>{{c.nom}}</td>
             <td>{{c.prenom}}</td>
             <td>{{c.Poste}}</td>
             <td><div class="checkbox">
                  <center><label>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="" name="check{{c.id}}">          
                          </label></center>
   </div></td> </tr>

      {%endif%}
            {%endfor%}
```

And finaly this is [image of my twig add a team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp5Zp.png)

Any suggestion how to get it work ? Thanks !

Comment: Have you read about [form collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is how I proceeded. In my EquipeType

```
 $builder
        ->add('date')
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('employes', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'OCUserBundle:Employe',
            'property' => 'username',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
```

And in my EquipeController

```
  foreach ($equipe->getEmployes() as $emp) {
                $emp->setEquipe($equipe);
                $em->persist($emp);
            }
```

And this is how I called it in my twig

```
{{form_widget(form.employes)}}
```

And that's it .. it works but I still have some issues in the twig I didn't know how to show them one by one. I think I'm going to post it in another subject . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can doing what you need with Ajax :

> In your js file

```
function check(checkbox) {
   if (checkbox.checked) {
      $.ajax({
          url: Routing.generate('your_route_name'),
          type : 'GET',
          data: $('#employee_code').val(),
      });
   }
}
```

> in your twig file

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkEmployee" onclick = "check(this)"/>
```

With this function `check`, you can verify if your checkox input in your table is checked and you call a method in a controller  that doing the rest!

Good luck!